# VBA - How to count the rank of the workers have been worked? (Calculation with the string(the rank) and variable)

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie of the VBA. I am facing a problem of convert the string to calculate the type of workers. Here is the situation: Let's say it is 10 of the people work in my company. Each of the people have different rank, for the example, such as Junior, Officer, Supervisor, Manager. I have made a multi-select Data Validation by List Box and stored the name of the workers(for example: Mary, Peter, Tom, Harry) have been worked at Cell A. With Cell B, I like to stored the rank of the workers have been worked based on the information from Cell A. (ie. Junior * 1, Officer * 2 , Supervisor * 1). And there is a variable P, that represents the half day or full day duty.

Here is the code of what I have been working on:

```
Dim rankR As Range
Set rankR = Worksheets("Data").Range("WorkerRankList")

With lstDV
        For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(x) Then
                If myRank = "" Then
                    myRank = .List(x)
                    strRank = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myRank, rankR, 2, False)
                    myRank = strRank & "*" & p
                Else
                    newRank = .List(x)
                    strRank = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(newRank, rankR, 2, False) & "*" & p
                    myRank = myRank & ", " & strRank
                End If
            End If
        Next x
End With
```

The result would be something like that: `Junior * 1, Officer *1, Officer *1, Supervisor *1`

Instead of what i want it to: `Junior * 1, Officer * 2 , Supervisor * 1`

How can I convert the result to calculation with the string(the rank) and variable P?

I know my English is bad. Thank you so much for the help.

==========

Updated on 22/3/2023

To explain my situation with more detail, I would like to make a example of the "WorkerRankList" and expected output.

WorkerRankList

| Name | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | Junior |
| John | Junior |
| Tom | Junior |
| Mary | Officer |
| Sally | Officer |
| Kelvin | Officer |
| Carrie | Supervisor |
| Gary | Supervisor |
| Rose | Manager |

Situation:

When I double click the cell of the Column for worker(for example, cell "A1"), a Userform shows. In the Userform, there is a ListBox named "lstDV" grab the worker name from WorkerRankList. When I select the worker name, the worker name will store at Cell "A1". And with the Vlookup function, the worker name will match with the relevant rank from WorkerRankList. The total manpower will store at Cell "B1".

## Case1

-Selected Workers: Peter, John, Tom, Mary, Sally, Carrie

-Full day work duty (which means p = 1)

The result I might got from my code:

```
Total manpower: Junior*1, Junior*1, Junior*1, Officer*1, Officer*1, Supervisor*1
```

My expected output:

```
Total manpower: Junior*3, Officer*2, Supervisor*1
```

## Case 2

-Selected workers: Peter, John, Tom, Mary, Sally, Carrie

-Half day work duty (which means p = 0.5)

The result I might got from my code:

```
Total manpower: Junior*0.5, Junior*0.5, Junior*0.5, Officer*0.5, Officer*0.5, Supervisor*0.5
```

My expected output:

```
Total manpower: Junior*1.5, Officer*1, Supervisor*0.5
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your range `Worksheets("Data").Range("WorkerRankList")`? Sounds like you may benefit from COUNTIFS to get what you want

Comment: Try using `strRank & " * " & p`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The "WorkerRankList" is a table like this: Column A are the name  of the worker(such as Peter, Tom, Mary, John, etc.), and the Column B are the rank of the workers respectively(such as Junior, Officer, Supervisior, Manager).

Comment: I think it would be really helpful if you could add a sample of expected output.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have updated the post and put the "WorkerRankList" and expected output on it. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary object to store each possible rank and associated to a 0 value. Then loop trough selected records and update the count in the dictionary and return your expected output.

Please, note my decimal separator is the comma and the code provied does not handle any errors, but it can be a starting point for you.

My form is like this and all the code is in the command button:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CMD_CALCULATE_Click()
Dim MyDict As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim rankR As Range
Dim RanksArray As Variant
Dim MyF As WorksheetFunction
Dim pValue As Double
Dim vRank As String
Dim FinalOutput As String
Dim MyKey As Variant

Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set rankR = Worksheets("Data").Range("WorkerRankList")
Set MyF = WorksheetFunction

'set p value (don't know where you get this)
pValue = CDbl(Me.TXT_PVALUE)

'add all posible ranks
RanksArray = Array("Junior", "Officer", "Supervisor", "Manager")

For i = LBound(RanksArray) To UBound(RanksArray) Step 1
    MyDict.Add RanksArray(i), 0
Next i

'now check what values are selected on lstDV and update dictionary
With lstDV
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 Step 1
        If .Selected(i) = True Then
            'worker selected, get their rank
            vRank = MyF.VLookup(.List(i), rankR, 2, 0)
            'update dictionary increasing 1 the rank
            MyDict(vRank) = MyDict(vRank) + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

'now the dictionary hold the total count of each rank. Just check if the value is zero or not
' also, apply your p value if the dictionary value is not zero. Loop trough dictionary

For Each MyKey In MyDict.Keys
    If MyDict(MyKey) <> 0 Then FinalOutput = FinalOutput & MyKey & "*" & pValue * MyDict(MyKey) & ","
Next MyKey

'get rid of the last comma on final output
FinalOutput = Left(FinalOutput, Len(FinalOutput) - 1)

'return final output
Me.TXT_RESULT.Text = FinalOutput

'clean variables
Set MyDict = Nothing
Erase RanksArray
Set rankR = Nothing
Set MyF = Nothing


End Sub
```

Also replicated your workers range:

[image]

The output I get following Case 1 and 2 is like this:

[image]

[image]

Please check this:

> [How to determine the items that are selected in a ListBox
> control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-determine-the-items-that-are-selected-in-a-listbox-control-7ad04b22-65ac-5f8d-1d3b-b774e2aa0d98)

> [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete
> Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Uploaded a sample to Google Drive in case you want to check it out: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BrllA7vpTB837pViIlsh3DUB44DYJEPX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: One might also fill `RanksArray` (or straightly `MyDict`) by covering each cell of column 2 of `rankR` reporting each unique value. This way one would not need to hardcode the ranks.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey indeed, of course. I focused the code on answering the question provided and harcoded the dictionary because it take less time, but you are right 100%.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Many thanks. I spent some time to learn the dictionary. This method is definitely what I need. It provide me the foundation to build up and improve my project. Thank you.

Comment: @Light Glad to help and glad to hear you learned something new! Dictionaries are really useful objects :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are better ways to obtain what you want (arrays, dictionaries), but considering the limited amount of information granted i've developed a little add-on to your code that edits your `myRank`. Add this at the end of your code:

```
    'Resetting variables.
    strRank = myRank
    myRank = ""
    
    'Covering each section of the string delimited by ",".
    For x = 0 To UBound(Split(strRank, ","))
        
        'Setting newRank as the given section (rank).
        newRank = Split(Split(strRank, ",")(x), "*")(0)
        
        'Checking if the given newRank hasn't already been processed.
        If Len(Replace(myRank, newRank, "")) = Len(myRank) Then
            
            'Adding newRank to myRank while also counting how many newRank have been specified in the record.
            myRank = myRank & newRank & "*" & (Len(strRank) - Len(Replace(strRank, newRank & "*", ""))) / Len(newRank & "*") & ","
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Removing the last "," if necessary.
    If Right(myRank, 1) = "," Then
        myRank = Left(myRank, Len(myRank) - 1)
    End If
```

---

---

---

## EDIT

Following the comments, here the updated version of the previous solution:

```
    'Resetting variables.
    strRank = myRank
    myRank = ""
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    
    
    'Covering each section of the string delimited by ",".
    For x = 0 To UBound(Split(strRank, ", "))
        
        'Setting newRank as the given section (rank).
        newRank = Split(Split(strRank, ", ")(x), "*")(0)
        
        'Checking if the given newRank hasn't already been processed.
        If Len(Replace(myRank, newRank & "*", "")) = Len(myRank) Then
            
            'Setting DblCounter.
            DblCounter = 0
            
            'Counting how many full-hour are there for the given rank.
            DblCounter = (Len(strRank) - Len(Replace(strRank, newRank & "*1", ""))) / Len(newRank & "*1")
            
            'Counting how many half-hour are there for the given rank.
            DblCounter = DblCounter + (Len(strRank) - Len(Replace(strRank, newRank & "*0.5", ""))) / Len(newRank & "*0.5") * 0.5
            
            'Adding newRank to myRank followed by DblCounter.
            myRank = myRank & newRank & "*" & Replace(DblCounter, ",", ".") & ", "
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Removing the last ", " if necessary.
    If Right(myRank, 2) = ", " Then
        myRank = Left(myRank, Len(myRank) - 2)
    End If
```

By the way: the previous code did return those strange results because of the splitting by ",". This way the first rank would have been (for example) "Junior" while another junior encountered down the line would have been labeled " Junior". Splitting by ", " instead of "," solved the problem.

As said: a solution using dictionaries or arrays will most likely be more elegant and appropriate. This one is more like a patch and not a tailored suit: easier to implement and functionally acceptable, but not the best way to do it.

---

---

---

## EDIT 2

Following the comments, here the updated version of the previous solution:

```
    'Resetting variables.
    strRank = myRank
    myRank = ""
    
    'Covering each section of the string delimited by ", ".
    For x = 0 To UBound(Split(strRank, ", "))
        
        'Setting newRank as the given section (rank).
        newRank = Split(strRank, ", ")(x)
        
        'Editing newRank to reduce the probability of rank partial overlapping (example: "Senior Officer" and "Officer").
        newRank = "|<|" & Split(newRank, "*")(0) & "|>|" & "*" & Split(newRank, "*")(1)
        
        'Adding newRank to myRank.
        myRank = myRank & newRank & ", "
        
    Next
    
    'Resetting variables.
    strRank = myRank
    myRank = ""
    
    'Covering each section of the string delimited by ", ".
    For x = 0 To UBound(Split(strRank, ", ")) - 1
        
        'Setting newRank as the given section (rank).
        newRank = Split(Split(strRank, ", ")(x), "*")(0)
        
        'Checking if the given newRank hasn't already been processed.
        If Len(Replace(myRank, newRank, "")) = Len(myRank) Then
            
            'Adding newRank to myRank while also counting how many newRank have been specified in the record.
            myRank = myRank & newRank & "*" & (Len(strRank) - Len(Replace(strRank, newRank & "*", ""))) / Len(newRank & "*") & ","
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Removing the tags.
    myRank = Replace(myRank, "|<|", "")
    myRank = Replace(myRank, "|>|", "")
    
    'Removing the last "," if necessary.
    If Right(myRank, 1) = "," Then
        myRank = Left(myRank, Len(myRank) - 1)
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But when there are two or more people at the same rank have been selected, the looping would continue to count. Let's say Peter, John and Tom are also "Junior", three of them have been selected. The result will be like this: `Junior*3, Junior*2`

Comment: Considering your update to the question, the only thing that my add-on won't cover is the half-day work (it will be counted as full-day). Otherwise my code should return a list of unique ranks followed by the number of selected employee with said rank. Have you tested it? Anyway, i will edit it considering the `p` variable.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. But the result is quite strange. With the "WorkerRankList" I have updated, let's say I have selected Peter, John, Tom (3 of them are Junior), the result will be like this: `Junior*3, Junior*2`. If I selected two Officer, the result is like this:`Officer*2, Officer*1`. If I select John and Sally, the result is correct showed as `Junior*1, Officer*1`. If I select all of the workers on the list, the result is like this: `Junior*3, Junior*2, Officer*3, Supervisor*2, Manager*1`

Comment: New code published. Feel free to test it and send feedbacks.

Comment: Many thanks for your code. It teaches me a lot. The ways of your usage of `len` to count the numbers of the newRank is so creative. May I ask why `Replace(DblCounter, ",", ".")` have to replace the "comma" to the "fullstop" within the DblCounter? Is it any chance that DblCounter could contain the "comma"? On the other hands, it could have a error in some special case. If a rank's spelling is same as other rank, such as Junior Officer, Officer, Senior Officer, the length of the `replace(myRank, newRank,"")` would not same as `myRank`, then cannot trigger the following code.

Comment: `Replace(DblCounter, ",", ".")` is there more for me than for you. You probably don't need it because your Excel uses points instead of commas as decimal separator (it's a language setting, basically). Since it won't affect the end result and it's not costly, i just left it there; you can remove it if you like and leave just `myRank = myRank & newRank & "*" & DblCounter`. For the `Replace(myRank, newRank, "")`: indeed, it could result in an error. We can avoid it by adding a "*" like `Replace(myRank, newRank & "*", "")`. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Sorry, I just come back from holiday. I tried to add a "*" as you advice but the error still occurred as before. When the first Office-like rank count the number and show in the result, such as "Junior Officer*1", the rest of the "Officer-like" rank(Officer, Senior Officer) would not reflected on the result.

Comment: I should have already edited the code. Have you tried the last version?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the edited code. Perhaps I should update my file to describe it more clearly. Double any cells under Column E, a userform show. All the worker ranks are worked, except for the Worker E. Since the Worker E's work position is "SART", choosing Worker E would not cause error but select Worker E, F, G, H, I together will only show "SART*1". Because Worker F to I are the "ART". I don't understand how to avoid this error by adding "*". Sorry for taking you that much time. [My file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B1laed6FMVzI63sP2m7SfMubTAMLdmT6/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Then it's a overlapping rank name problem. I've edited the answer adding a new code. Try it and send feedback. It might also be wise to check Foxfire And Burns And Burns' solution. It actually uses a dictionary and therefore it is the most proper solution. Might be request some work to be implemented in your existing code though.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tested the code and there are no further error occurred. I have learned a lot from you and "Foxfire And Burns And Burns".  Please let me know, should I do anything to close the question?

Comment: You might [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that has worked best for you personally in aswering your question/problem. You may accept one answer only. As said, my opinion is that a dictionary-based solution is more suited to achieve your goals. Therefore in my opinion Foxfire And Burns And Burns has granted the proper solution (although it probably wasn't a "copy-paste and go" solution). Mine, while effective, it's not tecnically the best one. It was meant to be implemented without major changes to your original code and based on limited informations.

Comment: I just accepted Foxfire And Burns And Burns's answer. I am so sorry for taking you that much time to answer my question and modified for me. I cannot even cast a vote to you since I don't have enough reputation. Hugh thanks for your help and advising!

Comment: Well done. And don't worry: i wouldn't have provided you with my assistance solely to get the points. Like (i guess) many here solving these problem is also a for-fun activity. It's the spirit of the a like engeneer: we like to solve interesting problems even for free. Just don't say that to our employers!